Adding Oauth 2.0 to Google Fact Check Tools API

I have a simple Python code to search through Fact Check claims using the Google Fact Check Tools API. I have updated the code to include OAuth flow and here is my code:
import requests
import google.auth
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import os
import json

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

GOOGLE_FC_API = "https://factchecktools.googleapis.com/v1alpha1/claims:search"
PAGE_SIZE = 3000
N_BACK_DAYS = 100
QUERY = "conspiracy"
API_KEY = "my_api_key"
credentials_file = './service_account_credentials.json'

class FetchFactChecks():
    def get_google_fcs(self):
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            credentials_file,
            scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/factchecktools']
        )

        # Request an OAuth2 access token
        credentials.refresh(Request())
        access_token = credentials.token
        headers = {
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
        }
        params = {
            'languageCode': 'en-US',
            'pageSize': str(PAGE_SIZE),
            'maxAgeDays': str(N_BACK_DAYS),
            'query': QUERY,
            'GFC_API_KEY': API_KEY
        }

        # Make the request to the Fact Check API
        response = requests.get(GOOGLE_FC_API, headers=headers, params=params)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("Success:", response.json())
        else:
            print(f"Error: {response.status_code}, {response.text}")  
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fc_factcheck = FetchFactChecks()
    fc_factcheck.get_google_fcs()

I am integrating this change as part of a larger workflow using GCP topics, Cloud Functions, etc. But when I run this program for testing, I get the following error:

{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
}

I have tried removing all the optional parameters except the mandatory parameter 'query' but still get the same issue. If I send the above request without any headers (oauth token), then it works.
Also I have tried using 'discovery' from googleapiclient using 'userinfo.email' as the scope for service account but still no luck.
from googleapiclient import discovery
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(credentials_file, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'])
delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('service_account_user_email')
service = discovery.build('factchecktools', 'v1alpha1', credentials=delegated_credentials)
rqst = service.claims().search(
   maxAgeDays=N_BACK_DAYS,
   pageSize=PAGE_SIZE,
   query=QUERY,
)
resp = rqst.execute()

Can someone please help on what's going wrong here?

I'm able to repro your issue. The documentation for Fact Check Tools API includes an email for the Google team supporting this service, perhaps contact them?

nice one thanks. I will reach out to them and see what they say

Ok. So I have emailed Google FCT API support and I have got an answer which says in short we don't need to make any changes to the code that uses API keys. Changes are needed to the scopes only if OAuth is already used for these APIs.
Response from Google Support:

The good news is that the search RPCs use API keys, not OAuth tokens,
so if you only use the search RPCs then there's nothing you need to
do. The tl;dr for the change is that anywhere where you already use
OAuth tokens, you'll need to update a small detail about how they're
created (specifically, add a scope unique to the FCT API). But you do
not need to start using OAuth tokens for an RPC if you're not already
using them.

Support have said that they will update the message to something more clearer and unambiguous in that FCT API page.
Hope that helps someone out there so they don't spend couple of days like me trying to get this to work :)
